# using format() multiple times in for loop with python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that will generate a very simple HTML table, its currently set up like so:

```
Point1HTML = """
  <tr>
  <td>{}</td>
  <td>{}</td>
  <td>{}</td>
  <td>{}</td>
  <td>{}</td>
  </tr>"""
```

then im calling format to write to a file using a whole bunch of lists as below

```
Point1HTML.format(ID[0], First[0].upper(), Second[0], Third[0].upper(), Fourth[0].upper())
```

When i join a tonne of these together and write to a file(using ID[1] etc) it works fine. But im now trying to get it to expand so it will be the same length as my ID List, so ive converted the variable ID into its length, then tried to use a for loop range to enter the info into the table lists, as they will all start at 0 and only be as long as the ID, example below

```
id = len(id)
for p in range(ID):
    HTMLFile.write(str(Point1HTML.format(ID[p], First[p].upper(), Second[p], Third[p].upper(), Fourth[p].upper())))
```

This throws out "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable". Can anyone help out :)... ive tried everything i can think of, this could be a typo because from what i understant, subscriptable errors have nothing to do with this

Comment: `for p in range(ID):` => `for p in range(len(ID)):`

Comment: dafuq... You are a legend thanks man...I dont get whats different from converting it prior... Any help on that would be appreciated as welll

Comment: oh, `ID` and `id` aren't the same: python is case sensitive. which probably explains your confusion!

Comment: I changed some of the variable names around and I notice now I look back over it that I really did a silly on my original.. thanks man